# Something's issuing CTRL_CLOSE_EVENTS but no one is logged in

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, scheduled-task

We're running an Azure server, Windows Server 2012R2. Just of late we've been seeing various scheduled console applications going down because they've received CTRL_CLOSE events.

However, no one has been logged in for some days.

Is there any way, from the system event logs or anywhere else, to know where these events have been coming from?

Comment: Are the scheduled tasks configured with the "stop task if it runs longer than" option?  That might result in a CTRL_CLOSE.

Comment: That is a possibility which I shall check as soon as I can. Thank you for a most helpful suggestion.